# New Macs keep asking about old discarded Mac credentials

Tags: icloud, apple-id, password, keychain

I have only been using modern Macs for a year or so now. I was due to get a 2019 MBP from work in early 2020, so I got a 2009 MBP a few months before that to orient myself.

I created an Apple ID and an iCloud account on the 2009 MBP. With a little difficulty, I was able to apply those credentials to the semi-locked-down 2019 MBP from work.

Since then I have

- done a fresh install of the 2009 MBP
- left the previous employer, returned the 2019 MBP, and started a new job
- bought a 2020 M1 MBA

During the 2009 MBP reinstall and the M1 MBA setup, I was asked for the login password on the 2019 MBP from my former job. I still remembered it, but that kinda freaked me out.

Now I'm about to get a new Intel MBP from the new job. I don't want the credentials from the previous 2019 MBP to be associated with my personal 2020 M1 MBA or the new job's Intel MBP in any way.

Does this make sense to any of you? How can I undo those links and not create any new links from the surrendered 2019 MBP to any future Macs I get?

### Update

Thanks to @jaune, I went to my Apple ID web page and looked at the Devices section. The 2019 MBP from my previous employer did not appear. I guess I need to learn more about the keychain, @jksoegaard !

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the edit to show us how the matter resolved. But your "edit" is actually an "answer," and should appear in an "Answer" box, not in the original question. It's OK to answer one's own question. You can copy your edit text, delete the edit (using the "edit" button below your question), then post a new Answer using the "Your Answer" button at the bottom of the page. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, I post my own answers all the time. But I don't consider it an answer. My edit shows the results of following the suggestion from @jaune , but it's not an answer because I didn't have the opportunity to disconnect the computer that's no longer in my possession. I need to learn more about the keychain and whether I should delete the whole thing or remove individual entries. I just got my new work computer and will report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens due to you having iCloud Keychain enabled. The Keychain is end-to-end encrypted so that Apple cannot decrypt the contents of your keychain on their servers.

When you add a new computer to your iCloud account, it tries to download the keychain to that computer. The contents cannot however be accessed with just the iCloud password - you will need to give the passphrase for the old device. Even though that device is really not around anymore, it was used to protect the Keychain originally, so its passphrase can help you unlock it now.

Note: The Keychain is not somehow "permanently" linked to your old computer. Now that you have started using your new computer, you do not need the old computer's passphrase anymore. If you choose to add new devices later, you will be asked to enter the passphrase of your new computer instead.

Comment: That makes sense that something in my iCloud required something other than the Apple ID for unlocking. I just wish I had been given the choice to unlock via either the 2019 MBP from the previous job **or** the 2009 MBP. I could check which "old" computer's credentials can be used to associate my soon-to-arrive new work MBP, _but maybe sharing keyring between work and personal computers is a bad idea?_

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that you forgot to sign out of iCloud on the 2019 MacBook Pro from your former job?

When setting up a new device, if iCloud Keychain is active, you will be asked to type the login password or passcode of another device that you are signed in to with your Apple ID, see [Approve a device to use iCloud Keychain](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/icloud-keychain-information-safe-mac-mh43699/11.0/mac/11.0#aria-mchlp09a4c42) for details.

**If you forgot to sign out of iCloud on one of your devices** and have given the device away, it could happen that Apple asks you to type the password of that device. In this case, **you will have to manually remove the device**, as explained in this support article: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205064. For example, using the Apple ID website:

1. Sign in to your Apple ID account page (https://appleid.apple.com), then scroll to Devices.
2. Click the device to see its details, then click "Remove from account."
   [image]
3. Review the message that appears.
4. Click again to confirm that you want to remove the device.

For more information on how Apple designs security, see the [Apple Platform Security](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/welcome/web) website.